# How to scroll a scrollview to come a subview in top in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll

I have a scroll view in my activity view,in this layout i will add dynamic content in 'ucontent','pcontent' by inflating another layout in a loop( the number of inflated layout changes with time).I need to scroll the scrollview sv so that the tiltle with 'titlep' comes in top when i click 'titlep'.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/sv"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#232323"
android:scrollbars="none" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#232323"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/titleu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#D84A49"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="7dp"
        android:paddingTop="7dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toggleu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/toggleu" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="title1....."
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ucontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/titlep"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#D84A49"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="7dp"
        android:paddingTop="7dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/togglep"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/toggleu" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:text="title2...."
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can i do that in my code or in xml?

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of your current screen? Anyway, try to add `<HorizontalScrollView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"` as a parent to the element you want to scroll. Remember, that every scroll view can only have one direct child.

Comment: i created scroll layout,and its scrolling fine,but my question is how to scroll programically on an  onclick event of linearlayout with id 'titlep' so that 'titlep' will be in the to of the screen

Comment: ah, okay, now I get you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this:

[Views](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

use  `isFocusable(true)`

and on the onClick use `requestFocus()`

Comment: thanx for the clue,isFocusable(true) method is not there,to set focus i used setFocusable(true).isFocusable() is to check whether is focusable or not